# is application must be published for in-app purchase in android?

Tags: android

i have uploaded one application to Googleplay store with billing permission. i want to buy that application using in app purchase. so i want to know whether that application should be published on GooglePlay store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not necessary to publish your application for testing in-app billing.

There are following two ways :

1: **Test your in-app without uploading your apk on google play store** :

> There are four reserved product IDs for testing static In-app Billing
>   responses:
>
> **android.test.purchased**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though you successfully purchased an item. The
>   response includes a JSON string, which contains fake purchase
>   information (for example, a fake order ID). In some cases, the JSON
>   string is signed and the response includes the signature so you can
>   test your signature verification implementation using these responses.
>
> **android.test.canceled**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID Google
>   Play responds as though the purchase was canceled. This can occur when
>   an error is encountered in the order process, such as an invalid
>   credit card, or when you cancel a user's order before it is charged.
>
> **android.test.refunded**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though the purchase was refunded. Refunds cannot be
>   initiated through Google Play's in-app billing service. Refunds must
>   be initiated by you (the merchant). After you process a refund request
>   through your Google Wallet merchant account, a refund message is sent
>   to your application by Google Play. This occurs only when Google Play
>   gets notification from Google Wallet that a refund has been made. For
>   more information about refunds, see Handling IN_APP_NOTIFY messages
>   and In-app Billing Pricing.
>
> **android.test.item_unavailable**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though the item being purchased was not listed in
>   your application's product list.

Source : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

2: **Test your in-app after uploading your apk on developer console in draft** :

> Again you have to follow some steps :
>
> a) Upload your signed apk and save it as draft (or send it for alpha
>   testing).
>
> b) Find Base64-encoded RSA public key in Services and APIs tab (use it in your in-app implemtation).
>
> c) Create In-app product and you will get a SKU (use it in your
>   in-app implementation).
>
> d) Actually step 'b' and 'c' are on higher priority than 'a' because you
>   have to use all these keys in your application before creating your signed apk.
>
> e) Activate this in-app product.
>
> f) Now install same apk in your device and try to use in-app billing.

Please find more elaborated and updated solution from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html).

Thanks

P.S. : It worked for me few days ago but it keeps on updating. Thanks.